# Get .attr() with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `data` element from multiple divs with the same class. Here is the code I got so far:

```
var dataArr = new Array();
$(".foo").each(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < $(".foo").length; i++) {
    dataArr[i] = $(this).attr("data");
}
});

$(".array").text(dataArr);
```

The problem with this code is that when you run it it stores only the last `data` on every index of the array. I have a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/AzRp2/

Comment: You had an extra for loop in your `.each` , there you go http://jsfiddle.net/d3Cq9/ . Next time please consider checking the [examples in the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) before asking questions here :) Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: come on! why the down vote?

Comment: @TamilVendhan Not me, but probably lack of research effort or usefulness which is what downvotes indicate.

Comment: Mmm, didn't knew I could do the `.each(function(i)` thing, that's why I put it twice there. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: I think, he is just getting started with the language. Beginners makes mistake. What they want is guidance not downvotes. Or atleast downvotes with comments.

Comment: @Gus While we're at good advice, consider not storing application state in your HTML, you can have a data JavaScript array to begin with instead of storing data in your HTML, each cell containing that numeric data (as numbers by the way) and a link to the DOM element. That way you don't have to query your DOM every time and you do proper [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Keep your presentation layer and business logic separate and you get to be a happy camper.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Benjamin! The data element on my HTML was just to use as an example, but I will keep your advice in mind. Again, thank you all for the help.

Comment: @Gus Sure, just remember, data attributes are a horrible broken approach, if you'd like to learn more SO has a JavaScript chatroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why do you have `for` loop inside an `each` loop.... actaully you dont need to use loop at all..use `map()`... **correct way to use HTML5 data attribute is `data-something`.. and you can use `data()` to get that value instead of `attr()`;**

**html**

```
    <div class="foo" data-test="111"> Hello </div>
    <div class="foo" data-test="222"> World </div>
    <div class="array"></div>
```

**jquery**

```
var dataArr =$(".foo").map(function(i,v){

   return $(this).data("test");

}).get();

$(".array").text(dataArr);
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AzRp2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Create an empty array
var dataArr = [];

// Loop through all the div's
$(".foo").each(function (index) {

    // Push the data into the array
    dataArr.push($(this).attr("data"));
});

// open console to see the array
console.log(dataArr);
```

Comment: If you're going to provide a solution to this (rather funny question) may I suggest .map ? It seems like an ideal fit. While we're there I think the native `Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("foo"),function(e){ return e.getAttribute("data");})`

Answer (score 1):

Did you wanted to do this?

```
var dataArr = new Array();
$(".foo").each(function () {
    dataArr.push($(this).attr("data"));
});

$(".array").text(dataArr.join(","));
```

Comment: I cross check before submitting you know.. Newbie ;-)